# Lost username on a Debian box

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

[image]

The situation is like this: I logged in to my Debian box through SSH and just found it showing the message that there is no username for the current account. I tried to use `whoami` to see if the system has the username but it seems that it lost it.

This box is shared with some other people and I asked the people who used it to see if they modified any files but no one touched any system files.

P.S. It is strange to be able to login to my box even the system has lost the username. Other things still works fine.

Comment: Have you tried another device?  The screenshot clearly depicts a mobile device.

Comment: Can you `su` to the root user? If so, check if your username still exists in `/etc/passwd`, under ID 1001

Comment: Please provide output of `ls -l /etc/passwd`. It looks like someone's changed the permissions - they should be `-rw-r--r--` and they're probably now `-rw-------`.

Comment: @CanadianLuke `su` is not working without a username but I have access to the root account. I followed the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@roaima is correct.

I was able to reproduce this error by removing the world readable flag:

$ chmod 600 /etc/passwd

And able to restore normal functionality by restoring it:

$ chmod 644 /etc/passwd

Comment: Processes in Linux can find out their user id, but need to consult this file to translate a user id to a name.  Your (hashed) passwords are safe because they are actually in `/etc/shadow` which should have much more restrictive permissions on your system.  `/etc/passwd` hasn't had any actual passwords in it on Linux for a long time, if ever.